# Add a drag&drop listener on an Eclipse view

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, listener

I am currently working on a RCP plugin, trying to add a DragAndDrop listener on my Package Explorer view in Eclipse.
All of my attempts failed, for several reasons :

1. I am not able to get a TreeViewer from my workspace (which is, I think, what I need to get).
2. I can get "views", but cannot add a D&D listener on them.

My main purpose is to be able to know when the user is moving a file into another folder, and get the source/destinations folders of the drag and drop event triggered by the package explorer.

Here is an example of what I have tried so far :

```
    for (IViewPart v : PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViews()) {
        if (v.getTitle().equals("Project Explorer")){
            System.out.println("##Found PE");
            //Add listener here ?
        }
    }
```

This code display the "Found PE" string, but doesn't allow me to add a listener.

Some precision : this code is running in a class inheriting from AbstracHandler, not in the UI Thread. I will consider moving the code if you think it is necessary.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You may be better using refactoring participants which give you lots of information about changes being made everywhere. See the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants`, `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.copyParticipants`, `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` and `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.moveParticipants` extension points.

Comment: I searched what participants were and how should I use them for the past 2 hours, but I should admit that I do not really understand the whole thing. Particularly about the arguments/type of arguments I have to provide, for instance, to a class extending RefactorModifications